# How to make my html work in the servlet code to redirect to another page?

Tags: java, servlets

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                     throws ServletException, IOException {     
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(); //create a session
    session.setAttribute("sessionname", "sessionvalue");

    out.println("Session value = " +session.getAttribute("sessionname"));
    out.println("Session ID is " +session.getId());
    out.println(session.isNew()); //checks whether the session is new or old
    out.println(session.getMaxInactiveInterval()); //Default 30 minutes 1800secs
    //session.invalidate();

    Cookie ck= new Cookie("Cookiename", "cookievalue");
    response.addCookie(ck);

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<form action=SecondServlet>");
    out.println("<input type=submit />");
    out.println("</form>"); 
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
```

SecondServlet.java

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();

    Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();

    for(Cookie ck: cookies){
        out.println(ck.getName());
        out.println(ck.getValue());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a submit button which redirects to another servlet class. But the submit is not being created how do i change it. These both servlet classes are working fine individually.

Comment: Didn't work. But thanks for responding

Comment: Where is the page are you're trying to redirect to, folder structure?

Comment: On clicking the submit button the first servlet page must be redirected to secondservlet class

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Onclicking the submit button in firstservlet class, it must display the cookie details from the secondservlet class

Answer (score 0):

you may do it like add action on submit of button

```
public void HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String location)
```

throws IOException

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code:

```
    response.sendRedirect("home.html"); // Redirects to home
```

Or

```
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: These are the only 2 servlets class i must have. There is no other code. Any changes must be done here.